# invoke pwndbg using just gdb command

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm currently using https://github.com/apogiatzis/gdb-peda-pwndbg-gef this script to install pwndbg, ged and peda. It invokes them with the respective commands

```
gdb-pwndbg
gdb-peda
gdb-gef
```

What I wanna do now is I wanna invoke pwndgb using just gdb command?
Where should I make changes to make that happen?
And what changes?

This is my .gdbinit file

```
define init-peda
source ~/peda/peda.py
end
document init-peda
Initializes the PEDA (Python Exploit Development Assistant for GDB) framework
end

define init-peda-arm
source ~/peda-arm/peda-arm.py
end
document init-peda-arm
Initializes the PEDA (Python Exploit Development Assistant for GDB) framework for ARM.
end

define init-peda-intel
source ~/peda-arm/peda-intel.py
end
document init-peda-intel
Initializes the PEDA (Python Exploit Development Assistant for GDB) framework for INTEL.
end

define init-pwndbg
source ~/pwndbg/gdbinit.py
end
document init-pwndbg
Initializes PwnDBG
end

define init-gef
source ~/gef/gef.py
end
document init-gef
Initializes GEF (GDB Enhanced Features)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just need to add a line
on top of my .gdbinit file

`source /path/to/gdbinit.py`

This solves the issue.